# Kaffeine not running anymore after trying Gnuradio

Tags: dvb-t, gnuradio

I have a strange problem with Kaffeine after trying Gnuradio. I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and Kaffeine was running out of the box with a RTL-2838 USB DVB-T stick.

After doing some experiments with Gnuradio I tried to watch TV with Kaffeine, but it doesn't recognize the DVB-T stick any more.

If I remember there used to be a `/dev/dvb` directory which is not created any more when I plug in the DvB-T stick.

```
lsmod |grep dvb
dvb_usb                24215  0 
rc_core                28662  1 dvb_usb
dvb_core              125650  2 dvb_usb,rtl2830

uname -a
Linux cuprum 3.16.0-28-generic #38-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 12 17:37:40 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 0ccd:00d7 TerraTec Electronic GmbH

dmesg
[ 5025.655244] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[ 5025.851120] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0ccd, idProduct=00d7
[ 5025.851126] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5025.851129] usb 2-2: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
[ 5025.851132] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Realtek
[ 5025.851134] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 00000001

dmesg |grep -i dvb
-- reports nothing --
```

If I remember correctly there used to be some DVB driver information in the `dmesg` output.

Also `w_scan` reports an error, `no usable terrestrial card found`.

Has anyone observed the same problem and maybe found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the cause of the problem.

One of the Gnuradio/rtl-sdr related packages has installed a file named:

```
/etc/modprobe.d/rtl-sdr-blacklist.con
```

This prevents the `dvb_usb_rtl28xxu`, `e4000` and `rtl2832` modules being loaded. For watching DVB-T they have to be loaded manually now. Blacklisting these modules is necessary, as they conflict with `rtl-sdr`.